# Using a-frame primitive to display 360 content

Tags: aframe, 360-virtual-reality

I am trying to use A-Frame to either display a 360 video or a 360 photo, but stumbled across some limitations of the a-entity framework: videosphere or sky are not accepted as an attribute, so:

this doesn't work: `<a-entity geometry="primitive:videosphere", ... ></a-entity>`

and this doesn't either: 
`<a-entity geometry="primitive:sky", ... ></a-entity>`

I searched the documentation but could not find why box, plane or sphere etc. do work with a-entity, but sky or videosphere do not.

The purpose of this question is: I want to write a piece of code that is able to show 360 videos and 360 photographs and switch from one content type to another. Is there a simple solution?

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

Neither videosphere, or sky, are geometry primitives. Here's the list of built-in [geometries](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/geometry.html#built-in-geometries).

To switch the photographs / videos, just keep a sphere, or sky:

```
<a-sphere material="side:back"></a-sphere>

<a-sky></a-sky>
```

and switch the `material.src` attribute via an registered component.
ou'll have to remember to manually call `play()` and `stop()` on the videos, for they might be playing in the background.